# Creating a "prev/next" for li list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I'm creating an li list which is generated by a PHP repeater that grabs the Wordpress' blog posts and places the titles in a full li list.

However, I'm trying to code it so only the first seven li's appear and to see the next or previous seven, you must click the "prev" or "next" buttons respectively.

Here is all I've got, I don't know where the best to begin regarding jQuery, what would be the best approach?

```css
ul > li {
  font-size: 25px;
  list-style: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding-left: 0;
  color: #000;
  
  -webkit-transition: all 0.35s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.35s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.35s ease;
  transition: all 0.35s ease;
}

ul >li:hover {
  padding-left: 30px;
  color: green;
}

.wrapper {
  float: left;
}

.wrapper a {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: red;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.wrapper .prev {
  float: left;
}

.wrapper .next {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <ul>
    <li>Message 1</li>
    <li>Message 2</li>
    <li>Message 3</li>
    <li>Message 4</li>
    <li>Message 5</li>
    <li>Message 6</li>
    <li>Message 7</li>
    <li>Message 8</li>
    <li>Message 9</li>
    <li>Message 10</li>
    <li>Message 11</li>
  </ul>

  <a href="#" class="prev">prev</a>
  <a href="#" class="next">next</a>
</div>
```

Comment: You  want to hide `Message 8,9,10,11`?

Comment: have you tried any jquery up to this point?

Comment: Yes, and to display then, you hit "next" and if you want to see the first seven again, you hit "Prev".

Comment: @Doug honestly mate, after all the JS I've written previously, I'm a bit stumped on where to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this is what you wanted.

`current` variable is used as a pointer to which `li` elements are currently visible. So whenever you click `.next` or `.prev` button this function shows all of the `li` elements and then hides the ones that are out of the range.

```js
var current = 0;
var $li = $(".wrapper li");

$(".prev, .next").on('click', function() {
  if ($(this).hasClass("next")) {
    current+= 7;
    if (current >= $li.length) {
      current = current - 7;
    }
  } else {
    current-= 7;
    if (current < 0) {
      current = 0;
    }
  }
  hideLi();
});

hideLi();

function hideLi() {
  $li.show();
  $li.each(function(i, e) {
    if (i < current || i >= current+7) {
      $(e).hide();
    }
  });
}
```

```css
ul>li {
  font-size: 25px;
  list-style: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding-left: 0;
  color: #000;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.35s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.35s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.35s ease;
  transition: all 0.35s ease;
}

ul>li:hover {
  padding-left: 30px;
  color: green;
}

.wrapper {
  float: left;
}

.wrapper a {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: red;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.wrapper .prev {
  float: left;
}

.wrapper .next {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <ul>
    <li>Message 1</li>
    <li>Message 2</li>
    <li>Message 3</li>
    <li>Message 4</li>
    <li>Message 5</li>
    <li>Message 6</li>
    <li>Message 7</li>
    <li>Message 8</li>
    <li>Message 9</li>
    <li>Message 10</li>
    <li>Message 11</li>
    <li>Message 12</li>
    <li>Message 13</li>
    <li>Message 14</li>
    <li>Message 15</li>
    <li>Message 16</li>
    <li>Message 17</li>
    <li>Message 18</li>
    <li>Message 19</li>
  </ul>

  <a href="#" class="prev">prev</a>
  <a href="#" class="next">next</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow, thank you so much. This is brilliant, I'm running through the jQuery now so I can use this again down the line. Thank you so much mate.

Answer (score 1):

I snuck most of my comments in the code ...
but in the spirit of "where to start":

1. Create a function that will hide/show sections of your list items
2. Pass that function a parameter that will help you determine which page you're viewing
3. Create previous and next functions to connect to your links
4. Add in a couple of sanity checks to make sure the code doesn't execute outside of its own bounds (like hitting "next" and ending up on a page 3 that doesn't exist)

This code isn't jQuery though, its traditional (vanilla) JavaScript.

```js
// set a global variable to track your "current page"
let currentPage = 1;
// set a global variable on how many LIs to show per page
let perPage     = 7;
// get the nodeList of all the LIs you wish to hide/show
// (paginate)
let liList      = document.getElementsByClassName('wrapper')[0].getElementsByTagName('li');
// find the total number of LIs available
let totalLis    = liList.length;
// find the number of pages...
// parseInt to strip away the decimals
// +1 because we're starting with 1
let totalPages  = parseInt( totalLis / perPage ) + 1;

// subtract from the global variable currentPage
// but don't let it go less than 1
function previous(){
  currentPage--;
  if( currentPage < 1 ){
    currentPage = 1;
  }
  page( currentPage );
}

// add to the global variable currentPage
// but don't let it exceed the totalPages count
function next(){
  currentPage++;
  if( currentPage > totalPages ){
    currentPage = totalPages;
  }
  page( currentPage );
}

function page( pageNum = 1 ){
  // Find the end range of pages you want to view
  let end   = pageNum * perPage;
  // Then subtract your perPage total to find the 
  // start value
  let start = end - perPage;
  // quicky sanity check to make sure you don't exceed
  // the available elements
  if( end > liList.length ){
    end = liList.length;
  }
  // hide ALL the list items
  for( let i=0, x=liList.length; i<x; i++ ){
    liList[i].style.display = 'none';
  }
  // but then show the ones within your chosen range
  for( let i=start, x=end; i<x; i++ ){
    liList[i].style.display = 'block';
  }
}
```

```css
ul > li {
  font-size: 25px;
  list-style: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding-left: 0;
  color: #000;
}

ul > li:nth-child(n+8){
  display: none;
}

.wrapper {
  float: left;
}

.wrapper a {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: red;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.wrapper .prev {
  float: left;
}

.wrapper .next {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <ul>
    <li>Message 1</li>
    <li>Message 2</li>
    <li>Message 3</li>
    <li>Message 4</li>
    <li>Message 5</li>
    <li>Message 6</li>
    <li>Message 7</li>
    <li>Message 8</li>
    <li>Message 9</li>
    <li>Message 10</li>
    <li>Message 11</li>
  </ul>

  <a href="javascript: previous()" class="prev">prev</a>
  <a href="javascript: next()" class="next">next</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Brilliant stuff Doug, seriously. Thank you so much for helping out here. Running through the code and your comments, definitely want to learn from this the best I can. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

its called pagination, please use data tables for that 
https://datatables.net/ check this site its based on java script try this or you can find lot of alternatives

otherwise you need to create php pagination script for that

Comment: I'll look into this! Thanks for bringing this up!

Answer (score 0):

> ### jQuery.slice()
>
> Reduce the set of matched elements to a subset specified by a range of indices.
>
> **Structure: `jQuery.slice(from, to)`**
>
> It's 0 based. So, jQuery.slice(7, 10) will select elements no 8,9,10 and 11.
>   [Here's the documentation](https://api.jquery.com/slice)

At first you need to hide `li` 8-11.

```
$("ul li").slice(7,10).hide()
```

Add a click listener to `.next` to hide first 7 `li` with `slice`.

```
$(".next").click(function(){
 $('ul li').slice(0, 6).hide();
}
```

Add a click listener to `.prev` to show first 7 again and hide 8-11.

```
$(".prev").click(function(){
 $("ul li").slice(0, 6).show();
 $("ul li").slice(7, 10).hide();
}
```